# Unity and Firebase Realtime database - How to read value data right from database (Beginning of the game)?

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

I'm developing a 3D game for Android platform in first person style. I'm using Firebase Realtime database as my data storing source. The idea is that in the beginning of the game, a variable is created to assign to it an instance of the table database itself. The table contains one key with one value only. This value is the number of seconds which is used as a timer straight from the start of the game (2,400 seconds). **I want with a function to retrieve this timer float value (2,400) from the data snapshot (The table) for assigning it to another variable and let the timer running.**

```
public void ReadTimeValue()
   {
  
   Debug.Log("read db function start");
    dbReference.GetValueAsync()
    .ContinueWithOnMainThread( Task => {
      if (Task.IsFaulted){
        Debug.Log("problem");
      }

      else if (Task.IsCompleted){
        DataSnapshot snapshot = Task.Result;
        Debug.Log(snapshot.Child("room_timer").Child("time_value").Value);
        time_value = (float)snapshot.Child("room_timer").Child("time_value").Value;
        Debug.Log("db import " + time_value);
      }}
    );
    Debug.Log("read db function end");

  }
```

I created a function for it, but without a success. I have read different posts to solve the problem, but still my request doesn't succeed.

Every help/idea regarding the code is appreciated, particularly with the request for the DataSnapshot of the database. Thanks in advance!

Comment: what's you're `Debug` says?

Comment: 12-30 11:02:38.948 24789 27951 I Unity   : before a db call
12-30 11:02:39.073 24789 27951 I Unity   : https://escaperush111-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com
12-30 11:02:39.073 24789 27951 I Unity   : after a db call
12-30 11:02:39.119 24789 27951 I Unity   : import2 2400
12-30 11:02:39.138 24789 27951 I Unity   : Firebase Analytics API Initializing
12-30 11:02:39.138 24789 27951 I Unity   : analytics API Initialized

Comment: regarding "import2 2400" - it's a result of  another function's debug.log()